# Apache-poi:Want to traverse an excel column and sum up the corresponding values present in next column

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have data in excel as follows:

```
Orgs    Bill
Org1    1.0
Org2    2.0
Org3    3.0
Org3    8.0
Org2    10.0
Org1    12.0
```

The result which i want is summing up the values corresponding to similar orgs:
Org1: 13.0
Org2: 12.0
Org3: 11.0

I can achieve this with below code. Just want to know if there is a better way to do it.

```
    List<String> duplicateOrgs = new ArrayList<String>();
    LinkedHashSet<String> orgs;
    LinkedHashMap<String, Float> orgsAndSum = new LinkedHashMap<String, Float>(); 

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Himanshu Chand\\Desktop\\OrgData\\OrgDataLarge.xls");
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    Workbook workbook = null;
    workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");

    int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum()-sheet.getFirstRowNum();

    for (int i = 1; i < rowCount+1; i++)
    {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
        duplicateOrgs.add(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());   //here i am looping through the first column and storing all the orgs in a list.
    } 

    orgs= new LinkedHashSet<String>(duplicateOrgs); //storing the list into set to get unique orgs.

    Iterator value = orgs.iterator(); 

    while (value.hasNext()) 
    { 
        String org=(String) value.next();
        float sum=0;
        for (int i = 1; i < rowCount+1; i++)
        {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
            if(org.equals(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue()))
            {
                sum=(float) (sum+row.getCell(1).getNumericCellValue()); //now comparing the set of orgs with the first column and summing the bill wherever there is a match.
            }
        } 
        orgsAndSum.put(org, sum);
    } 

   for (Entry<String, Float> entry : orgsAndSum.entrySet())
   {
       System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
   }

}
```

Comment: Use countifs(), one for each org.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it by hand you can use a `COUNTIF` function, either directly in the Excel spreadsheet or with [`org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Countif`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/functions/Countif.html) class. Take a look at  [Formula Examples](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/examples.html#common-formulas) to see how POI handles build-in Excel functions.

Comment: Countif or countifs ? Is it a typo or will both work?

Comment: @SolarMike thanks, corrected myself. There is both `COUNTIF` and `COUNTIFS`.